# Create HTTP GET Header Request

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, http-headers

I am using php and I want to create a HTTP request to access some API data. I have a document that says, I need to place the following request

```
GET /abc/api/Payment HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-PSK: [App Key]
X-Stamp: [UTC Timestamp]
X-Signature: [HMACSHA256 base 64 string]

Body:
var1, var1
```

I have app key, I can get UTC Timestamp and I can create signature. I am not sure how to start creating this request? I am using codeingiter. If someone can help with example to set the header and body?

I also tried this url https://www.hurl.it/ to place requests but can't make it work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use cURL's `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

This should get you started

```
function request($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlOpts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "X-PSK: [App Key]",
            "X-Stamp: [UTC Timestamp]",
            "X-Signature: [HMACSHA256 base 64 string]"
        ),
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    // If there was an error, show it
    if (curl_error($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: Looks Great, I am trying it now, just a question the first line in question says GET /abc/api/Payment HTTP/1.1 do I ignore it? or we can use it some how?

Comment: @SyedSajid - That's the path you want to pass into the function. Of course you'll need the full URL, with that path in it.